# Unable to compile EF6 in modern PCL library (VS 2015 RTM)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api2

I'm new to .NET core (http://docs.asp.net/en/latest/conceptual-overview/dotnetcore.html) and VS2015 (RTM) so I'm probably missing something obvious, yet I cannot find clear suggestions by googling around and I'm trying to learn.

I'd like to create a vNext WebAPI application using Entity Framework 6. If I add this package to the `project.json` file (`"EntityFramework": "6.1.3"` under dependencies), VS gets the package and installs it as expected. No problem here. Anyway, I'd like to use a more structured solution, consisting of:

1. my **core models** in an "old-fashioned" PCL library targeting .NET framework 4.6, ASP.NET Core 5.0, Windows Universal 10.0. Essentially, here I keep my entities POCO classes and the interface representing my data repository.
2. my **EF-based repository implementation**, using the above models, in a "modern" PCL library.
3. the **vNext WebAPI project** (a good starting point for this is http://www.asp.net/vnext/overview/aspnet-vnext/create-a-web-api-with-mvc-6) should use both the projects listed above, injecting the EF-based implementation of the interface defined in the core project.

Thus, I added EF as a dependency in project (2), so that its `project.json` looks like this:

```
...
  "dependencies": {
    "System.Collections": "4.0.10-beta-23019",
    "System.Linq": "4.0.0-beta-23019",
    "System.Threading": "4.0.10-beta-23019",
    "System.Runtime": "4.0.10-beta-23019",
    "Microsoft.CSharp": "4.0.0-beta-23019",
    "Bredit.Core": "1.0.0-*",
    "EntityFramework": "6.1.3"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "dotnet": { }
  }
...
```

(As for the `dotnet` moniker I did not know of, I found some info at http://blog.nuget.org/20150729/Introducing-nuget-uwp.html).

Now, if I try to add my class derived from `DbContext` here I get tons of compilation errors which look like EF is not included, e.g. `CS0246  The type or namespace name 'DbContext' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`, and the like for the `System.Data` namespace.

If I include the same EF dependency in the WebAPI project directly, no such errors arise, yet this dependency there is defined in the same way. Could anyone explain what's exactly going on here?

Comment: try EF7 Beta6 and not the old EF6.

Comment: Wow thanks for the fast reply! :) Anyway, before upgrading to EF7 I wanted to stick to EF6. My codebase does not use EF6-only features which were dropped, but EF7 being still in beta I fear this might be too much :). Just wanted to know if using EF6 is an option, as it would seem from the docs (and from the fact that it seems to work fine when installed in the web project directly), or I have better forget it and go for 7.

Comment: afaik EF6 simply doesn't support what want to do. You must use EF7

Comment: Thank you, I've just tried but I keep getting the same errors. I added EF7 via package manager console, as explained at http://ef.readthedocs.org/en/latest/getting-started/aspnet5.html#install-entity-framework. Further, don't know if this is related, it seems that I'm not able to add a reference to the core PCL from the modern PCL: if I check it in Add reference, it is not added at all. This sounds puzzling for me and threatens the whole concept of layered implementation, at least in these terms.

Comment: After further research, I found at least some info about the PCL reference issue: see e.g. https://github.com/aspnet/Home/issues/674. Project.json-based projects do not have the notion of assembly references. It seems there are 2 options here: either pack the dependencies into NuGet packages, or use dnu wrap (which anyway seems buggy). I confess I'm beginning to doubt whether it will be convenient to start a vNext project now, or rewrite a traditional ASP.NET later (I'd really like to avoid this, given that vNext is a completely different beast).